# Launch Java application in background mode in Windows

Tags: java, windows, background, launch

I need to launch a Java application in background.

The Java application is a console application (a listening service), The application is launched with a instruction like this

```
java app.jar
```

I need to launch this application and, during the application execution, the console does not stay open.

It is valid that the application opens and then closes

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this solution can help you, but you can use a combination of two types of scripts, bat and vbs.

the first is a classic bat script

```
java app.jar
```

the second is a vbs script, this script launches the first script in background mode

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "script.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

if you launch the second script, the console is not shown